# In the sentence who is saying "that's your business,isn't it ,cousin"

Tags: word-choice, word-order, word-formation

Laila remembered another fight, and, that time, Mammy had stood over Babi and said in a mincing
way,That's your business, isn't it, cousin? To make nothing your business. Even your own sons going
to war. Howl pleaded with you. Bui you buried your nose in those cursed books and let our sons go
like they were a pair of haramis.

Comment: But who is say isn't is ,cousin?

Comment: *Mammy had stood over Babi and said …* I find nothing confusing about this. It's Mammy who's talking. Perhaps the remaining sentences are unclear as to speaker versus narrator, but there's nothing unclear about who saying *That's your business, isn't it, cousin?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Googled the first phrase and found it [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=k7hIAw5WmmwC&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=%22Laila%20remembered%20another%20fight,%22&source=bl&ots=IiIpdP7SjC&sig=ACfU3U3CKYA_1byGYhut-YWJBaDI6k1_1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy7_CJ4vzkAhV4ThUIHWmCC9sQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Laila%20remembered%20another%20fight%2C%22&f=false), where it's clear (because it's in italics) that all of it after 'a mincing way' is spoken by Mammy. Laila is remembering Mammy saying it.

Comment: Who said isn't cousin?

Comment: Click on the link in my answer and you will see that - as I said - all of it after 'a mincing way' is spoken by *Mammy*. That is why it is in italics.